# Reading php file and looking up mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file

I have two columns in a table (MYSQL database)

One column contains an alias and the other contains the real name

Coln1:The_Spiderman  coln2:-Peter,J,Parker

** Note: Coln 1 is actually the name of the file. So, it cannot contain special characters.
However, Coln2 can contain commas

I have a csv file which contains a set of values that are actually present in Col1 of the said table. They can contain spaces, underscore.

What I am planning is to do the following:

a) Read from csv file each values one by one
b) Using that value do a lookup on mysql table and get the real name
c) Write the real name to the same csv file

I have some experience in php but I am not able to put all of these together.

Can someone help me?

Thanks
Sash

```
**ANSWER:**
```

Thanks @briosheje for your tips
Here is what I came up with:-

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("group.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pwd","dbname");

        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 

        {

            $query = "SELECT name FROM table where alias = '" . $data[$c] .  "'";
            $result = $link->query($query) OR die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                {

                    $fp = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
                    fwrite($fp, $row["name"].PHP_EOL);
                }


       }
    fclose ($fp);
    }
}

fclose ($handle);
```

Comment: This is not the place to ask people to do all the work for you. Ask specific questions, show what have you tried, etc..

Comment: @dragoste Was my first question. I will get better as I go ahead

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve data from your CSV use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

It will return you an array with the data contained in the CSV.

To elaborate the data, do the comparison you want using your SQL query (after connecting to the database, of course, I assume you know how to do that).

Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) if you don't know how to query a database using PHP.

After quering the database and doing the comparison, assuming in your CSV file there wont be any repetition, replace the value of the array returned by fgetcsv with what you need, then use [fputcsv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to finish the job.

Hope this gives you the idea!

Comment: The requirement was not necessarily a csv input and output so it was straightforward I believe. Thanks much

Comment: You're welcome, sir, it was just to give you the Idea, usually the best solution is to give idea instead of writing 100 lines of code that you probably won't like to see :P (To be honest, I thought you needed to do this job, that's why i proposed to use fputcsv and fgetcsv!)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to pull out mysql records via PHP. Then you must follow 5 simple steps.

1. Connecting database
2. Selecting Database
3. Perform database query
4. Use returned data.
   and finally

5.Close connection.

The steps 1,2 and 5th are same everywhere. ITs th 3 and 4th which really changes page to page and using that yo can extract values.

Example - >

```
include('config.php'); // Your database config


 if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 

  $q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $login_db_table WHERE id='" .                                mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'") or die('Database error.');
  $user = mysql_fetch_array($q, MYSQL_ASSOC); 

?> 
<h1><?= $user['username'] ?></h1>
```

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated so don't use it in examples.